# Changing border and background colors of a table and hovering over them

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to change the background and border of a table by the click of a button. I am also trying change the colors by hovering over the buttons. I got the hover to work, if i do it first.  The problem that I am having is that when I click a button to change the background color, I can not click any other button to change to that specific button color.  For example, I have four buttons, blue, green, yellow, red.  If I click the blue button, the background will change to blue, then if i choose to click the other colored buttons, it will not work and also my hover will not work anymore after I click any button once.  Also, How can reduce coupling. At the rate I'm going if I add more color buttons, that only equal more line of code.

```
 <h1 class="underline">Choose a Background or Border Color</h1>
            <div class="divCenter">
                <div class="divTable" ></div>
            </div></br>
        <button id="button1">Blue</button>
        <button id ="button2">Green</button>
        <button id="button3">Yellow</button>
        <button id ="button4">Red</button></br>
        <button id="button5">Blue Border</button>
        <button id ="button6">Green Border</button>
        <button id="button7">Yellow Border</button>
        <button id ="button8">Red Border</button></br>
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function()
            {
                $("#button1").click(function()
                    {

                        $(".divTable").attr("class","divTableBlue");
                    }); 

                $("#button2").click(function()
                    {
                    $(".divTable").attr("class","divTableGreen");

                    });
                $("#button3").click(function()
                    {
                    $(".divTable").attr("class","divTableBlue");
                    });
                $("#button4").click(function()
                    {
                        $(".divTable").attr("class","divTableRed");
                });
        $("#button1").hover(function()
                    {
                        $(".divTable").addClass("divTableBlue");
                    }, 
                    function() 
                    {
                        $(".divTable").removeClass("divTableBlue"); 
                    });
                $("#button2").hover(function()
                    {
                        $(".divTable").addClass("divTableGreen");
                    }, 
                    function() 
                    {
                        $(".divTable").removeClass("divTableGreen");
                    });
                $("#button3").hover(function()
                    {
                        $(".divTable").addClass("divTableYellow");
                    }, 
                    function() 
                    {
                        $(".divTable").removeClass("divTableYellow");
                    });
                $("#button4").hover(function()
                    {
                        $(".divTable").addClass("divTableRed");
                    }, 
                    function() 
                    {
                        $(".divTable").removeClass("divTableRed");
                    });
            });
        </script>
```

CSS is

```
.divTable
{
    display:table;
    padding-top:10px;
    padding-bottom:200px;
    padding-left:10px;
    padding-right:10px;
    width:250px;
    background:grey;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:5px;
}
.divTableBlue
{
    display:table;
    padding-top:10px;
    padding-bottom:200px;
    padding-left:10px;
    padding-right:10px;
    width:250px;
    background:blue;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:5px;
}
.divTableGreen
{
    padding-top:10px;
    padding-bottom:200px;
    padding-left:10px;
    padding-right:10px;
    width:250px;
    background:green;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:5px;
}
.divTableYellow
{
    padding-top:10px;
    padding-bottom:200px;
    padding-left:10px;
    padding-right:10px;
    width:250px;
    background:yellow;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:5px;
}
.divTableRed
{
    padding-top:10px;
    padding-bottom:200px;
    padding-left:10px;
    padding-right:10px;
    width:250px;
    background:red;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:5px;
}

.divTableBlueBorder
{
    display:table;
    padding-top:10px;
    padding-bottom:200px;
    padding-left:10px;
    padding-right:10px;
    width:250px;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:5px;
    border-color:blue;
}
.divTableGreenBorder
{
    padding-top:10px;
    padding-bottom:200px;
    padding-left:10px;
    padding-right:10px;
    width:250px;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:5px;
    border-color:green;
}
.divTableYellowBorder
{
    padding-top:10px;
    padding-bottom:200px;
    padding-left:10px;
    padding-right:10px;
    width:250px;
    border-width:5px;
    border-style:solid;
    border-color:yellow;
}
.divTableRedBorder
{
    padding-top:10px;
    padding-bottom:200px;
    padding-left:10px;
    padding-right:10px;
    width:250px;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:5px;
    border-color:red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

See if this is what you expected: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/YjzmY

You can reduce you code into:

```
var colors = [                       //first make a list of colors.
    "Blue",
    "Green",
    "Red",
    "Yellow"
    ],
    selected = "";                   //later used to store selected color
```

Then make a function:

```
function seperate(arr,j){            //created a separate function
    return function(){               // to store i given by the loop.
        $(".divTable")
            .attr("class","divTable")
            .addClass("divTable" + arr[j]);
        selected = arr[j];
    }
}

function seperate_hover(arr,j){
    return function(){
        $("#button"+(j+1)).hover(function(){
                $(".divTable")
                .attr("class","divTable")
                .addClass("divTable"+arr[j]);
        },function(){
            $(".divTable")
                .attr("class","divTable")
                .addClass("divTable"+selected);  //change back to the selected color.
        });
    }
}

function doTheJob(arr) {
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        $("#button" + (i + 1)).on("click", seperate(arr,i));   //click
        seperate_hover(arr,i)();                               //hover
    }
}

doTheJob(colors);​                   //the script will now do the job for you
```

Also, use `.on("click")` instead of `.click()`.

Comment: I use the above the first block of code to reduce it, but it still didn't help me figure out the answer to my question..

Comment: also, when i did use..it only only me to hover over the first color index.

Comment: @user1392576 - See if this is what you wanted: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/YjzmY/ (edited)

Comment: Thanks alot everyone. It gave me insight on how to approach my problem.  it was more simple than the way I was doing.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$('target').on('click', function(){
     //add your code
});
```

Instead of `.click()`